# Array of markers in ios

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

In my application i have to display 15 places belong to city, if the user taps on any place i need to display the details of that place in a info window using some text and images.
I already tried and created a marker and info window using google documentation. But to create 15 markers what is the best way, to create the markers one by one 15 times or can we use arrays
THank YOu.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google maps sdk documentation there is no way to add markers in a bulk fashion therefore you must add them one at a time.

See the following: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker

Comment: ok Thank you.. can we use an array to store the coordinates location